# Is the following convergence of the series of functions uniform?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For the series f(x) = x + [sum from j=1 to j=infinity, x((1-x)^j)], I already proved that this series converges pointwise for x on [0, 1]: f(x) converges pointwise to 1 if x is on (0, 1]; f(x) converges pointwise to 0 if x=0. Note that I found that for x on (0, 1], the partial sum of this series is Sn(x) = 1 - ((1-x)^(n+1))

However, is such convergence uniform? How can I formally prove it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use LaTeX for mathematics in this: your question is almost impossible to understand as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the convergence were uniform then by the uniform convergence theorem the limit function would also be a continuous function, but the limit function you calculated is not continuous. Hence the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks!